# Probability of edges between nodes of a specific type

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Given a network with $G(n, p)$ with $n = 3600$ vertices and an edge probability of $p$.
The set of vertices consists of three different types of vertex: $type_i$, $type_j$ and $type_k$. The proportions of those types are known: 80% of $type_i$, 15% of $type_j$ and 5% of $type_k$.

An edge is said to be of $type_{(i, j)}$ if it connects a $type_i$ vertex and a $type_j$ vertex. The graph is without self-loops and undirected, so edge $type_{(i, j)} \equiv type_{(j, i)}$.

What are the expected number of edges of each type? So:
$type_{(i, j)}$, $type_{(i, k)}$, $type_{(j, k)}$, $type_{(i, i)}$, $type_{(j, j)}$ and $type_{(k, k)}$?

Here's what I got so far:

- $P(type_{(i, i)}) = 0.8^2$
- $P(type_{(j, j)}) = 0.15^2$
- $P(type_{(k, k)}) = 0.05^2$
- $P(type_{(i, j)}) = 2 \times 0.8 \times 0.15$
- $P(type_{(i, k)}) = 2 \times 0.8 \times 0.05$
- $P(type_{(j, k)}) = 2 \times 0.15 \times 0.05$

The sum of all probabilities gives 1, so that seems about right.
To get the number of channels of a specific type, you would do the following for each type:

$p \times 3600 \times P(type_{(i, i)})$

My solution seems to disregard the fact that the graph doesn't self-loop, but I figured that with enough vertices that wouldn't make a difference.

Are my assumptions correct? Is the math right? Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but made a mistake in the end.

The probabilities of each type, for a given existing edge are ok.

For each potential edge, then the probability of each type is indeed $p\times P\left(type_{\cdot,\cdot}\right)$.

But when you are taking the total expected number : You do not have 3600 edges. You have 3600 vertices, hence $$\binom{3600}{2} \text{ possible edges}$$

Comment: Thanks! There's something about the actual words edges and vertices that makes me mix them up from time to time. This is not the first time this has happened to me.